# Custom UIBarButtonItem/UISegmentedControl for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, facebook, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Currently I would like to make my UINavigationController have the look and feel like facebook's main view.

[image]

I was thinking about using a UIsegmentedControl which would have a transparent background with an image inputted into the button's view.

Another idea was creating custom buttons with their background image as an image.

If anyone has any ideas on how this is done or an example project I can refer to, please REFER me!!! Haha.

Thank you stackoverflow!!!

Answer (score 1):

in this case i would just use standard UIBarButtonItems for the left and right ones.
The center would then be a custom view with 3 buttons inside.
UINavigationItem has a property called 'titleView'.

So in some appropriate controller just do s.th. like:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myCustomViewWithThreeButtonsAsSubviews;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myLeftUIBarButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myRightUIBarButtonItem;
```

setting the styles of the barButtontem to UIBarButtonItemStylePlain and providing images will do the job easily.

Comment: But what about clicking on the button? I wanted the buttons to become a different color or rather, onbuttonpress I would like the user to see a button pressed, like the Facebook app. I feel like this idea would limit the animation when clicking the button. Sure I can have some type of action happen when the button is pressed but will the user be able to see the buttons image change from normal to highlighted?

Comment: I guess this is an easier way to ask this question, "would i be limited to highlighting the button on buttonpress?"

Comment: UIBarButtonItems in the navigation bar can't have the UIBarButtonItemStylePlain--they are always bordered.

Comment: So i take it I would need to create an entirely custom navigationbar?

Comment: @Scott, you can add a custom button to the titleView, it doesn't have to be a UIBarButtonItem, and it doesn't need a border. What you said is only true if you're adding bar button items directly to the navigation bar.

Comment: @rdelmar: Are you saying that setting a `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` (or `rightBarButtonItem`) will work? I've never really tried it that way, so I always thought it wasn't possible without some sort of workaround.

Comment: @Scott, no, I'm saying that you can add plain UIButtons to the titleView, which itself can be added to the navigation bar (and replaces the normal title).

Comment: @rdelmar: Yes, but Felix' answer says "setting the styles of the barButtontem to UIBarButtonItemStylePlain and providing images will do the job easily", which is not true because that's an unsupported configuration. I'm not sure if the original question included the left/right bar buttons, but simply setting UIBarButtonItems with the plain style wouldn't work in that case.